# Filter/sanitizing email subject and body in PHP

Tags: php, email, phpmailer, html-email, sendmail

I'm using PHPMailer to send emails.

Now, we all know we need to always check user input.
But how about the subject and body of emails? (so i do not mean the emailadress)

What does need to be sanitized and how to do it? What are the (major) vulnerability's?

Should i'll use something like HTMLPurifier for this? Because i want the user to be able to markup there emails. Or should i'll use/write a BB-code function what can be used?

**Update:**

*For mail body:*
I now use htmlspecialchars with ent_quotes flag on. After this ill run a BB-code (jBBCode) parser over the message. This one looks safe now.

*For subject:*
I do not use any validation/sanitizing/etc. (exept min and max strlen) on the subject field.
Tested with some javascript but it looks like it's all okay.

Can i assume this is safe now? (P.s. the code does not get printed anywhere else than in the email.)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you need to clean user input before sending. HTMLPurifier and HTMLawed make a fair job of sanitising, but need to be tuned to not block out useful stuff - both err on the side of caution. BBCode or markdown do make things much easier to filter, so long as you don't need to do intricate layouts.

Comment: Please have a look at my updated question again and give me your thoughs. I'll updated some information.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
<?php
filter_var($body, FILTER_SANITIZE_FULL_SPECIAL_CHARS)
```

to help protect against special characters also you can use RAW such as

```
<?php
filter_var($body, FILTER_SANITIZE_RAW, FILTER_FLAG_ENCODE_HIGH)
```

Full details can be found here -> https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php

Comment: Those will make things safe, but won't allow any markup to work.

Comment: using this error like : Use of undefined constant FILTER_SANITIZE_RAW - assumed 'FILTER_SANITIZE_RAW' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP)